# React-router (0.13) + Flux - how to get flux class instance into willTransitionTo hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, react-router

I have a container component for all routes that need authorized access. But I need a universal lifecycle hook to ask Flux store "is user logged in?". The problem is that `static willTransitionHook` doesn't have access to props (or context):

```
class AuthenticatedHandler extends React.Component {
    static willTransitionTo(transition) {
        // `this.props.flux` is not accessible
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('did mount', this.props);
    }

    render() {
        const { flux } = this.props;

        return (
            <FluxComponent flux={flux} connectToStores={{
                user: store => ({
                    isLoggedIn: store.isLoggedIn(),
                    user: store.getUser()
                })
            }}>
                <RouteHandler />
            </FluxComponent>
        );
    }
}
```

What solution you propose? Use `componentDidMount` + `componentDidUpdate`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no way around that. If you want to receive `flux` as prop you cannot rely on `willTransitionTo`.

You can, however, use `componentWillReceiveProps`, which, I believe, is called by the React Router.

If you want to *disallow* the transition in the first place, though, I'm not sure how you should proceed.